# Huobi REST API - signing requests - Verification failure

Tags: rest, sha256, hmac, signing

I have problem with Huobi (cryptoexchange) REST API request-signing. Rules are clear (e.g. [here](https://huobiapi.github.io/docs/dm/v1/en/#signature-authentication-amp-verification)). Example for "v1/account/acounts" - GET with no params:

1. URL params:
   `AccessKeyId=dbye2sf5t7-d5829459-bf3aee27-67f62&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2020-11-11T12%3A17%3A57`
2. Pre-signing text:
   `GET\napi.huobi.pro\n/v1/account/accounts\nAccessKeyId=dbye2sf5t7-d5829459-bf3aee27-67f62&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2020-11-11T12%3A17%3A57`
3. Hmac SHA256-Signature of Pre-signing text with private key (verified [here](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online)):
   `auZl70i2qsUb7+U9yYEEY1bwzLypWIM7qF1pBAJcvfc=`
4. URL to GET: `https://api.huobi.pro/v1/account/accounts?AccessKeyId=dbye2sf5t7-d5829459-bf3aee27-67f62&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2020-11-11T12%3A17%3A57&Signature=auZl70i2qsUb7%2BU9yYEEY1bwzLypWIM7qF1pBAJcvfc%3D`

And the response is:

`{"status":"error","err-code":"api-signature-not-valid","err-msg":"Signature not valid: Verification failure [校验失败]","data":null}`

What I'm making wrong? I have searched thru many code-examples and no error found...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. In fact, sometimes it will work while other times it wont, and I can't find any rhyme or reason for the erratic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the same endpoint. I'm not sure what code you're using to sign your requests. Here's mine:

```
class HuobiAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, api_key: str, secret_key: str) -> None:
        self.api_key: str = api_key
        self.secret_key: str = secret_key

    @staticmethod
    def create_sign(p_params: Dict, method: str, host_url: str, request_path: str, secret_key: str):
        sorted_params = sorted(p_params.items(), key=lambda d: d[0], reverse=False)
        # encode_params = urllib.urlencode(sorted_params)
        encode_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(sorted_params)
        payload = [method, host_url, request_path, encode_params]
        payload = '\n'.join(payload)
        payload = payload.encode(encoding='UTF8')
        secret_key = secret_key.encode(encoding='UTF8')
        digest = hmac.new(secret_key, payload, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
        signature = base64.b64encode(digest)
        signature = signature.decode()
        return signature

    def __call__(self, request: requests.PreparedRequest) -> requests.PreparedRequest:
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
        params_to_sign = {'AccessKeyId': self.api_key,
                          'SignatureMethod': 'HmacSHA256',
                          'SignatureVersion': '2',
                          'Timestamp': timestamp}
        host_name = urllib.parse.urlparse(request.url).hostname.lower()
        params_to_sign['Signature'] = self.create_sign(params_to_sign, request.method, host_name, request.path_url, self.secret_key)
        request.url += '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(params_to_sign)
        return request
```

My original problem was that instead of using `request.method` I had a hardcoded "POST", which I must have copied from the original source.

Example usage:

```
requests.post(url, json=your_data, auth=HuobiAuth(key, secret))
```